# Como inverte as variáveis?

Tags: java

Escrever um programa em Java com o que é pedido abaixo.

A - Declare as variáveis X, Y e Z do tipo int.
B - Atribuir 10 à variável X.
C - Atribuir 2 à variável Y.
D - Com a ajuda da variável Z inverter os valores de X e Y.
E - Imprimir os valores das variáveis X, Y e Z respectivamente.

Obs. Estou começando o curso de Java agora e não estou conseguindo fazer essa questão, alguém pode mim ajudar?

Comment: Demonstre que teve algum esforço e mostre o que tentou editando a pergunta e adicionando, mesmo que não faça o pedido no problema.

Comment: O que já tentou? Qual a dificuldade que está tendo? Poste seu código. O Stackoverflow não é um site para buscar códigos prontos

Comment: Adicione um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tenta desta forma:

```
public int X,Y,Z;

X = 10;
Y = 2;

//Inversão
Z = Y; //Z = 2
Y = X; //Y = 10
X = Z; //X = 2

//Assim inverteu-se os valores de X e Y
```

Comment: Você acha legal da um código pronto a quem está aprendendo? Dessa forma você não está ajudando ninguem a aprender nada

Comment: Mas que código pronto? Isto é um problema simples de inversão, que outra forma teria de o ajudar? Eu não postei apenas código, fui explicando o que estava a acontecer. É assim tão mau aprender com exemplos?

Comment: Sim voce deu um codigo pronto, nem esperou o autor editar a pergunta com o que ele tentou. ou explicar qual era a duvida dele, especificamente.

Comment: Não consigo entender porque vocês perdem mais tempo com essas coisas, do que a ajudar o pobre rapaz. Eu apenas fui prático e tentei ajudá-lo da melhor forma que consegui. Eu acho que ele vai aprender, porque eu fui explicando o que estava a acontecer, não dei o código por dar. Já reparaste que em 4 comentários teus, nenhum serviu para ajudar o rapaz na dúvida dele?

Comment: Voce leu os 2 comentarios na pergunta? O site nao funciona assim, aqui ajudamos quem demonstra esforço em aprender, a questao do jeito que está, mesmo que nao seja a intencao do autor, parece pedido de codigo pra exercicio de escola, coisa que nao é aceito no site. Por isso incentivamos a ele a mostrar o que tentou, e tentar ajuda-lo na duvida dele, e nao entregar pronto, voce nao está ajudando ninguem entregando a resposta de um exercicio, ao inves de esclarecer a dificuldade de quem está fazendo

Comment: Talvez tenha errado, só quis tentar ajudar